# Asus Zenbook/Samsung MU6103 Miracast keeps on disconnecting after 10 minutes

Tags: windows-10, laptop, graphics-card, tv, miracast

I have a:

- [Asus Zenbook UX430UNR laptop](https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX430UN/HelpDesk_Download/) with latest Windows 10 Pro Version 1909
- [Samsung UA55MU6103WXXY 4K Smart TV](https://www.samsung.com/au/tvs/uhdtv-mu6103/UA55MU6103WXXY/) with latest firmware 1280.5

When I connect the Asus laptop to the Samsung Smart TV after 10 minutes it disconnects and it's hard to reconnect.

This is what I've done:

- Updated to latest driver for graphics card using Asus LiveUpdate
- Updated to latest driver for WiFi card using Intel Update download
- Updated to latest firmware for TV using inbuilt software updater
- Updated to latest BIOS firmware for laptop using Asus LiveUpdate

  ---
- Factory reset Windows 10 Pro
- Verified that the driver and hardware supports a wireless display using `dxdiag`
- Verified that the system supports a wireless display using an alternate method (`netsh wlan show drivers` command in a command prompt)

  ---
- Tried a LG V30+ Android mobile or Google Nexus 7 tablet device on the Samsung TV. This works fine.
- Tried connecting the Asus laptop to a different LG webOS UM7600PTA smart 4k TV. This works fine.

I've spent a few hours on Microsoft Directly support; Samsung TV Support and Asus support.

I've asked for support on the web here:

- This is my Microsoft Windows 10 [Feedback hub report](https://aka.ms/AA6w0lk).
- This is my [Product Review question](https://www.productreview.com.au/questions/87f9b298-b39c-4a3e-8b97-527386d05572) perused by Samsung representatives.
- This is my [Asus Zen community support forum post](https://www.asus.com/zentalk/thread-298045-1-1.html).

Any suggestions?

The relevant hardware:

- Intel® Core™ i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz
- Intel® UHD Graphics 620 with latest drivers 23.20.16.4973 dated 2018/02/28
- Intel® Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265 with latest drivers 20.70.13.2 dated 2019/09/10
- [Samsung UA55MU6103WXXY 4K Smart TV](https://www.samsung.com/au/tvs/uhdtv-mu6103/UA55MU6103WXXY/) with latest firmware 1280.5 connected to Wifi Router on 5GHZ band.

---

## Update 2020/01/03

- Updated Intel® UHD Graphics 620 to latest drivers 20.70.15.1 dated 2019/12/31
- I forgot to mention. Samsung HQ had me connect both the TV and laptop to my mobile hotspot. They didn't specify the frequency band but it was also 5GHZ.
- Samsung TV repairmen (Video Factory Electronics) came out but only tested their Android mobile to my Samsung TV which of course works as I"ve already told Samsung HQ. There was not good communication from Samsung HQ and Video Factory.

Still has issue.

Comment: Please don't just come and post your question into chat. However, have a upvote for actually doing some research.

Comment: Regarding: "Tried a LG V30+ Android mobile or Google Nexus 7 tablet device on the Samsung TV. This works fine."
and
"Tried connecting the Asus laptop to a different LG smart 4k TV. This works fine."
This is all using the Miracast feature, I presume, and thus, eliminates any one element as an obvious culprit.
Is there any way you can connect your TV to your network via ethernet (wired), to see if that makes a difference (and of course the Laptop).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Miracast uses WiFi Direct so it shouldn't make a difference  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miracast

Comment: @Darryn - since we don't know why it isn't working, and given the number of things you've already tried, 'shouldn't make a difference' seems a bit naive!  Looks like Miracast can work over LAN as well as WiFi - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-mice/9598ca72-d937-466c-95f6-70401bb10bdb?redirectedfrom=MSDN so can you at least try it to see if it DOES make a difference? I can't think of anything else to try.

Comment: @Steerpike Thanks for the web link and time to do research. I know that HDMI works fine but  that doesn't solve the wireless problem. Yes Miracast can work over infrastructure using direct physical connection but WiFI Direct is what I'm testing.  Let's assume displaying on TV works over Ethernet. What then?

Comment: @Darryn - honestly, I have no idea. It sounds like you've tried everything reasonable, and for me when I get to that point, I start trying 'secondary' ideas. Sometimes, solutions appear when you try less obvious things. Maybe, when you run over ethernet, an error message will appear that reveals the root cause of the problem ... you just don't know till you try it.  But - if it's a pain to try, maybe not worth it.

Comment: @Steerpike I just had TV Repairmen over and all they did was test Miracast on their Android mobile. They saw that it wasn't working on my laptop.

Isn't their radio protocol analyser or logs on the laptop that can help me out? Thinking back that was what I was hoping they would have.

Answer (score 1):

I see your specs at [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/wireless/wireless-products/dual-band-wireless-ac-8265.html) 

TX/RX Streams   2x2  Bands 2.4 GHz, 5 GHz

 (May want to try and only use **2.4GHz**).

A lot of places out there don't support 5G yet.


Intel has put out a new driver also Windows 10 Wifi package drivers: 12/31/2019  [21.60.2](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/29258/Windows-10-Wi-Fi-Drivers-for-Intel-Wireless-Adapters) 
Hope this helps you out.

Comment: How do I force Miracast to only use 2.4Ghz?

Comment: Try setting __your__ laptop band to use 2.4 GHz.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and answer. Remember it's Miracast so uses WiFi Direct. So would it be a different adapter? Anyway trying the latest drivers.

Comment: No, not a different adapter, you might just try and setup your wifi to use 2.4GHz. __How to Connect to 5GHz Wifi on Windows 7/8 and 10__ https://appuals.com/how-to-connect-to-5ghz-wifi-on-windows-7-8-and-10/ Your very welcome Peace ;)

Comment: Updating drivers to latest made no difference. Testing out **2.4GHZ**.

Comment: OK it won't connect if I connect to wifi router via 2.4GHZ but will if I connect via 5.0GHZ and then transfering to 2.4GHZ is fine. And it seems to work for longer then 5 minutes. This is an ok workaround for the moment.

Comment: You are really doing alot of researching and testing. I am glad your making progress. I am going to vote your question up and giving you a big A+ for all your status updates. Hope I helped, if even a little. Peace.

Answer (score 1):

### Temporary Workaround

- Connect the laptop to WiFi router via 5GHZ; then connected Miracast; then switched laptop to Wifi router via 2.4GHZ. This works fine for longer then 30 minutes so far.

However this is not a long term fix as 2.4GHZ is slower then 5GHZ. I am still not sure what the root cause issue is.